Identification of an IC labeled S3t
A chip found in a Ducati motorcycle dashboard. It had a little water and it got burnt. So the chip used to control all the light indicators no nothing turns on. The small writing on the chip is "S3t"


It's a Nexperia PBLS4003Y dual transistor.


Thank you very much
